# blank value captures while scraping using Rselenium

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I am trying to scrape a textbox value from the URL in the code. I picked the css using slector gadget. It is not able to capture the content in the text box. Tested several other CSS toobut the textbox value is not captured. 
Text box is  : construction year
Please help . Below is the code for reference.

```
url = "https://www.ncspo.com/FIS/dbBldgAsset_public.aspx?BldgAssetID=8848"
values = list()
remDr$navigate(url)
page_source<-remDr$getPageSource()
a = read_html(page_source[[1]])
=        html_nodes(a,"#ctl00_mainContentPlaceholder_txtConstructionYear_iu")

values = html_text(html_main_node)
values
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above answer also works. But if you are only trying to use `RSelenium`. Here is the code

```
library(RSelenium)
checkForServer()
startServer()
Sys.sleep(5)
re<-remoteDriver()
re$open()
re$navigate("https://www.ncspo.com/FIS/dbBldgAsset_public.aspx?BldgAssetID=8848")
re$findElement(using = "css selector", "#ctl00_mainContentPlaceholder_txtConstructionYear_iu")$clickElement()
text<-unlist(re$findElement(using = "css selector", "#ctl00_mainContentPlaceholder_txtConstructionYear_iu")$getElementAttribute("value"))
```

This works

Answer (score 1):

Why RSelenium? It scrapes fine with rvest (though it is a horrible SharePoint site which may cause problems down the end with maintaining the proper view state cookies).

```
library(rvest)

pg <- html_session("https://www.ncspo.com/FIS/dbBldgAsset_public.aspx?BldgAssetID=8848")

html_attr(html_nodes(pg, "input#ctl00_mainContentPlaceholder_txtConstructionYear_iu"), "value")

## [1] 1987
```

You should be grabbing the `value` *attribute* vs the node text. This should work in the your selenium code, too.